# Can I directly battle my friends?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know the main VS mechanic in Pokemon GO is the gyms but I have yet to find a local gym as I live in a somewhat rural area.  Can I have a battle directly with my friends or do I need to find a gym to try the VS aspect of the game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to battle someone else other than the Asynchronous Gym Battles. But this may change in the future versions of the game, as it's a very expected feature in any Pokémon game.